# Confused about permission of group `www-data` for `/var/www/html'

Tags: server, permissions, php, nginx

My `/var/www` is this (permissions 755)

```
drwxr-x---  3 www-data www-data 4096 gen 11 16:27 www
```

My `/var/www/html` is this (permissions 755)

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 gen 11 16:27 html
```

> NOTE: if it's important, I installed **php 7.2** and **nginx** on a **Ubuntu 16.04.5**; that for say that I manually created `/var/www` and `/var/www/html` because not created from nginx's installation

My user is named `mirko`

And using command `group mirko` I can see I am member of `www-data`

```
mirko : www-data adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare
```

But I cannot write files in `/var/www/html`. Of course, it because of `755` permissions.

**question: the 755 is the suggested permission for `/var/www/html` in a lot of tutorials; but in this way, how is supposed I manage file into this folder?**

My user must be able to run a `composer create-project` for example, and also `git pull` and so on.

**What's the right settings for shell user and folder?**

> I know I can simply add +w recusively. My question was: if suggested permissions for `html` folder is `755`  (or even `750`) and suggested ownership is `www-data:www-data`...  ***how can a shell user access html subofolders?***

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that you are a member of `www-data`? I can't see `www-data` in your output. try logging out and relogin after adding your self to `www-data`: `sudo gpasswd -a mirko www-data`

Comment: You can use `775` for folders and `664` for files. `chmod -R g+w /var/www/html
`.

Comment: @Ravexina: thanks !! Was just a copy/paste error. I'm really member of www-data

Comment: @RoVo: thanks, I know I can simply add +w recusively. My question was: if suggested is 755 and suggested ownership is www-data:www-data... haw can a shell user access html subofolders?

Comment: please reference the "suggested ownership", who is telling that ?

Comment: I see every where; https://askubuntu.com/questions/767504/permissions-problems-with-var-www-html-and-my-own-home-directory-for-a-website just to be one.

Comment: @Rovo: OMG !!! The solution was is the link I just pasted !!! the ownership shuold be 'user:www-data' !!!!! I am so stupid ...

Comment: And then you can give `g+w` for files that `www-data` needs write access. You can write the answer best by yourself I guess ;-)

Comment: Since OP indicated the linked question they were looking at had an answer that fixed, I have closed this as a duplicate, mostly because it's the same general problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ownership should be `youruser:www-data`
And `youruser` should be in `www-data` group

Permissions for folders 750, for files 640

This can be done by one command: `chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o= /pathtofolder`

If scripts used to create some files add group writable permission to needed folders(like smarty template cache)

Comment: There is a problem: when I create new files, the setgid bit is ignored, so new files are owned by "mirko:mirko" instead of "mirko:www-data". Why?

Comment: are folder group also www-data? I don't know, with gid bit it should be fine, try to create file in other program to test

Comment: Updated answer with "And `youruser` should be in `www-data` group", I think that was the problem with setgid ignored