# I am constantly getting 403 errors in Apache Ubuntu, regarding aliases in apache 2.4

Tags: permissions, apache2

I've done several hours of research. I am running Ubuntu 22.04, I am on the latest release and I am not doing anything special or fancy to my computer. I've gotten to the point where I successfully am able to get my pages to display PHP properly, so, that isn't an issue. I would think that it would be easy to find out documentation to successfully create aliases. I notice there are some courses from LinkedIn Learning in their library, however, they are from 2018. I wary of about Apache especially when I've read elsewhere that there have been changes between versions 2.2 and 2.4 for Apache. This is my code so far. When I type in test1, it does not link to the file. These are the permissions for my files so far

```
4-rw-r--r-- 1 jake jake 19 Jun 13 02:30 index. 
4-rw-rw-r-- 1 jake jake 19 Jun 13 02:46 test.html. 


<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is/home/jake/Documents/coding
 #used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

Alias "/test1" "file:///home/jake/Documents/coding"
<Directory "file:///home/jake/Documents/coding/home/jake/Documents/coding">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>




    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Unless someone else has a better idea is `<a href="https://askubuntu.com/questions/767504/permissions-problems-with-var-www-html-and-my-own-home-directory-for-a-website">this correct</a>`? Should you never even think about trying to make your folder point somewhere else in the first place? I have seen other people try to do this and they have not been successful. What's interesting is anything by default outside of the Apache 2 does not seem to work. At first glance and after my research, I get the impression that it is actually hard to access by default. While they let you change a whole lot,

Comment: Rather than random "research" I would first pay more attention to the basics such as careful copy-pasting.  For example `# value is not decisive as it is/home/jake/Documents/coding`.  Or more importantly `<Directory "file:///home/jake/Documents/coding/home/jake/Documents/coding">` which contains an obvious problem you haven't noticed aside from the fact that using URIs instead of plain absolute paths isn't going to work.

Comment: The # will comment it out anyways? 
Secondly, I tried it with and without the file and it still didn’t work, so, I would suggest your comment is extremely unhelpful and suggests I haven’t tried it the normal way?

Comment: There are other people who have had issues like mine- https://askubuntu.com/questions/767504/permissions-problems-with-var-www-html-and-my-own-home-directory-for-a-website?noredirect=1&lq=1, when I talk about research, that should be obvious by my links.

Comment: Your question suggested that.  Do you still not see the problem with `/home/jake/Documents/coding/home/jake/Documents/coding`.

Comment: @Jake you realize you duplicated your path *twice* right?  That's the issue Martin is referring to.  You probably did NOT mean to copy/paste your home directory path there twice in your config.

Comment: @ThomasWard umm no? According to the documentation, you are supposed to first put it in the Alias, and then, in the directory xml tag (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html)?

Comment: @Jake you're looking at the wrong line.  Look at the line AFTER the Alias line.  This one is incorrect, the file path is wholly incorrect.  `<Directory "file:///home/jake/Documents/coding/home/jake/Documents/coding">`  <-- Nonexistent Directory, so your Alias 403ing is because you don't define it in your config.  You shouldn't need to have double entry for your directory paths here - I guarantee you 100% that `/home/jake/Documents/coding/home/jake/Documents/coding` does not exist on your system.  Your alias may be right, but your Directory configuration is wrong.

Comment: Further, `file://` is a URI, *NOT* a directory path, so your Apache configuration will not work in the Directory declaration because it needs the actual paths on disk not your `file://` URL.

Comment: I’ll try it with that fix, but, I could swear that I tried it without the file:/// and the issue was still the same. I will confirm later. I would not have made this post if I didn’t try just with the /home directory and not using the file:///.

Comment: @ThomasWard this is my code right now- "Alias "/test1" "home/jake/Documents/coding"
<Directory "home/jake/Documents/coding/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>", when I go to the Alias /test1, I am still getting the error. I now see the duplicate error that I made. That fix didn't work.

Comment: Now that I fixed that error, I'm getting a path not found issue @ThomasWard

Comment: @ThomasWard hi, I have come across a workaround which involves using soft links pointing the /var/www folder to another folder outside of the /var/www. While it is very hard and seems to be sandboxxed going the outside in, I seem to be able to work going the inside out. After I learn more about the topic, can I mark this as a potential answer later?