# apache2, user www-data is in group of personal account, but access is still forbidden

Tags: permissions, apache2

after `apache2` install, I added this user `www-data` to the group of personal account `hosek`.

```
root@hp:~# groups www-data 
www-data : www-data hosek
root@hp:~#
```

Group permissions to `DocumentRoot` folder are OK.

```
hosek@hp:/home$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  4096 kvě  1 23:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root  root  4096 kvě  1 22:32 ..
drwxr-x--- 24 hosek hosek 4096 kvě  3 15:53 hosek
hosek@hp:/home$
```

But when I access site, it shows me Forbidden. Why?

Just note, when I set `x` for `others` on `hosek` folder, it works. But it should work in 1st case?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

What is best practice in case you want website data in specific folder? About security related to `/var/www/html/` via `ssh`, read level-up folders is possible, for example you can see files in `/var` or in `/`.

How can I restrict this browsing folder on level-up related to `ssh` connection? It is good practice? And really only this way?
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-restricting-ssh-user-session-to-a-directory-chrooted-jail/

Maybe some complete manual would be very useful?

Thank you.

Comment: For security reasons I'm going to direct you to https://askubuntu.com/questions/767504/permissions-problems-with-var-www-html-and-my-own-home-directory-for-a-website/767534#767534 which explains how to *not* use your home directory for access to site data, etc. but *not* have things in your home dir.  Not to plug my own answer, but it's *safer* to not run things in your home directory space and just give yourself permissions elsewhere to access your website files (in `/var/www/` space for instance as my answer explains)

Comment: OK, in case I have all data in home folder (backup reason - because in past I forgot on `/var/www/html/` folder due reinstallation and I lost actual website data), what is best practice? Create `ln` from `home` to `/var/www/html`? Thanks.

Comment: Did you Logout/Login after you made the changes to groups? Group membership is handled by `login`.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Comment: @waltinator Yes, I did, same situation.